# How to enable hibernate.order_inserts property for a single session

Tags: hibernate

I'm going to enable `hibernate.order_inserts` in order to improve my batch insert operations.
As I can see, this is a property of session factory level. However, I consider enabling such property a little bit risky for all inserts my application do.
Is there an option to enable `hibernate.order_inserts` property for a single session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching through the hibernate source codes ,when the [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) is built by [Configuration.buildSessionFactory()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#buildSessionFactory%28%29)  , [SettingsFactory.buildSettings()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/SettingsFactory.html#buildSettings%28java.util.Properties%29)   will be called internally to parse the hibernate configuration properties into the [Settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html) instance.  The `hibernate.order_inserts` will be strode into the `orderInsertsEnabled` property of the [Settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html) instance.

The [Settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html) instance then passed to the constructor of the [SessionFactoryImpl](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl.html) which is an implementation of the [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) and assign it to its internal [settings properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl.html#getSettings%28%29) . This [settings property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl.html#getSettings%28%29) is declared to be [final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) which its value cannot be changed once it is set.

The `orderInsertsEnabled` property of the [Settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html) is  exposed to the client through the getter [isOrderInsertsEnabled()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html#isOrderInsertsEnabled%28%29) . Searching the code again and confirm that  there is only one place ([ActionQueue.sortActions()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/ActionQueue.html#sortActions%28%29))  to call this getter which the [Settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Settings.html) instance is exactly get from the [SessionFactoryImpl](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl.html)

As a result ,  I don't think there have any options to change `hibernate.order_inserts` during run-time no matter it is on the session factory level or session level. So you have to create another session factory with `hibernate.order_inserts` set to enable to achieve your purpose.